# How to fetch config block from orderer after renewing expired certificates

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How to renew orderer certificates in HLF after all the certificates including root CA is expired? I am running a HLF 2.2 network wherein my root certificate had validity of two years which expired last month, all the orderer and peer components certificates are also expired. I renewed my root CA certificates and generated new msp and tls certificates for all components.By following FAB-18384, I was able to bring up orderer container by adding these configuration to docker:
     `- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_TLSHANDSHAKETIMESHIFT=10000h - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_TLSHANDSHAKETIMESHIFT=10000h - ORDERER_GENERAL_AUTHENTICATION_NOEXPIRATIONCHECKS=true`

I replaced old msp certificates with newly generated one, but when I am trying to fetech systemchannel config block, I am getting connection timed out with new orderer ca, with old orderer ca I am getting: **Error: can't read the block: &{FORBIDDEN}**. How can I read the config block?